# @Secured annotation by grails plugin vs the standard one

Tags: grails, spring-security

Are there differences with the Secured annotation of grails spring security plugin and the standard spring security one?

Base on the docs: (http://grails-plugins.github.io/grails-spring-security-core/guide/requestMappings.html#securedAnnotations)

> You can use an @Secured annotation (either the standard
>   org.springframework.security.access.annotation.Secured or the plugin's
>   grails.plugin.springsecurity.annotation.Secured which also works on
>   controller closure actions) in your controllers to configure which
>   roles are required for which actions. To use annotations, specify
>   securityConfigType="Annotation", or leave it unspecified because it's
>   the default

It seems that either works in our project, but to avoid problems down the line, I just want to be sure.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The plugin's annotation has all of the features of the standard Spring Security annotation, and a couple more. I originally added it to the Acegi plugin to be able to annotate controllers, which at the time could only be implemented as Closures, and the standard annotation was only configured to work on methods and at the class level. Recently I added support in the 2.0 plugin to specify security rules in annotations using Groovy closures, which of course isn't a core Spring Security feature.

In both Spring Security and the plugin, the annotations are used to add security checks or proxies, and as such are primary information containers. I configure that in the plugin similarly to how it's done int core Spring Security, but I can't use their code directly because of the way Grails works. But in both cases, the extracted data is used to build Spring Security data objects that are then used to do the heavy lifting, and those are identical (or effectively identical). This is similar to how GORM works with Hibernate - in the end Hibernate does the work based on information gathered at build time, and in regular apps the comes from hbm.xml files and annotations, and in Grails it comes from looking at the domain classes.